# Can I merge and then split ducts to resolve a space issue?

Tags: hvac

I had sweating ducts. I pulled the drywall down and wrapped all the ductwork--the main stack, two 4 inch ducts and two 6 inch ducts--in my dining room and into the kitchen.

I got to one spot where the two 6 inch ducts go through the main truss in the center of the house. The builder put a third truss butt up against the main support truss but they did not line up the openings. They squished the two 6 inch ducts down to about 2 inches to get through the opening.

I don’t have anywhere I can rerun this. Can I put put a Y pipe on the two 6 inch ducts to reduce it to one 6 inch pipe then put another Y pipe on the other side to go back to 2 ducts?

Answer (score 1):

You can...but do you need to?

If you have a square duct, 4x4", it has a cross section of 16 square inches.

If you squish it to 2x8", it still has a cross section of 16 square inches.

I think it's good the way it is and you aren't losing any airflow.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It makes sense, the only problem is because the builder squished two 6 inch ducts through the opening. It leaves no room to wrap insulation around it. The wood and drywall are wet from the sweating ducts. Everywhere else I wrapped seems to have stopped the sweating. If I don’t wrap this area, it will continue to drip.

Comment: I understand.   Maybe spray foam?

Comment: A 4x4 duct cannot be squished to 2x8. It would have to gain 4" of sheet metal. A circle is the most efficient circumference-to-area shape (a square being the most efficient _rectangle_), so any deformation reduces area and therefore flow.

Answer (score 1):

You technically could, but that solution doesn't gain you anything.

It's mostly a matter of cross-sectional area (with friction being a minor factor). Will doing what you describe increase it? I don't think so. A 6" round duct squished to 2" wide still has at least half its original area. Two of them, therefore, add up to more than one 6" fully round duct. You're better off with the situation as it is now.

Comment: This is essentially the same as Steve's answer from a year ago. Not sure why it got down voted, either. However, a _key_ detail that the OP is concerned about was mentioned in a [comment](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/202913/can-i-merge-and-then-split-ducts-to-resolve-a-space-issue#comment367872_202925) on that answer, and not in the question - insulating the duct work to prevent condensation. This has my vote (as it stands), as does Steve's.

Comment: It has some crucial distinctions form Steve Wellens' answer. He made some faulty statements about shape and area. It's _not_ good the way it is, but it can't be improved by the proposed solution.